# Firebase firestore queries are not filtering data, even when using where in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, stream-builder

I'm trying to use `where` in a Firebase firestore query in my flutter application but it is showing all the data in the collection without filtering it ., here is my code :

```dart
  Widget buildingMessages() {
    print('message room id $roomID'); //The correct id is being printed here
    var theMessages = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages');
    theMessages.where('room_id',isEqualTo: roomID).orderBy('created', descending: true);
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: theMessages.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
//....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `stream: theMessages.snapshots()`. You are referencing the **theMessages**. and you are not using your where clause. extends it with your where clause. like

```
stream: theMessages.snapshots().where(
                  'room_id',isEqualTo: roomID).orderBy('created', descending: true);
```

**Edit:** Or initialize it as

```
var theMessages = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').
            where('room_id',isEqualTo: roomID).orderBy('created', descending: true);
```